# Nothing happens when I click a link inside my webview

Tags: java, android

This is a part of my android app, i have created a webview...but when i click on any link inside the webview...nothing happens....here is my code...i want to launch the link either in any browser or any installed download manager...i m  a newbie..please help me out with this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    // no need to use title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // set webview as main content only
    mWeb = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(mWeb);
    // set Javascript
    WebSettings settings = mWeb.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // the init state of progress dialog
    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait for a moment...");

    // add a WebViewClient for WebView, which actually handles loading data from web
    mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // load url
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // when finish loading page
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }


    });
    // set url for webview to load
    mWeb.loadUrl("http://vesit-d7b.host22.com/Assignments/ECCF.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code and check that your url is being caught by the webview or not.

```
       myweb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
                       Toast.makeText(this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

see what url is coming when you click the link.....

```
   mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    // load url
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.v("here","the link is ::" + url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

and then copy it on browser to see whether it is a valid link or not..

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh remove the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method it will work